# Mark treeNode as selected (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a simple JTree.
I set it's selected node in the code via setSelectionPath().

Everything works fine for that but what I want is that the respective node (the end of my path) is highlighted as if the user had clicked on it with the mouse so that there is also a visual feedback in the tree itself to indicate which node is selected.

Greetings Raven

EDIT:
How I want it to look (just like it looks when selecting a node with the mouse
[image: Properly highlighted (after selection with mouse)]

How it currently looks after selecting node via program
[image: Current result after selecting node via program]

Comment: Do you use: myTree.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(treeModel.getPathToRoot(treeNode))) ?

Comment: Yes I tried that one but it didn't make any difference from my current approach...

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: just found out that in my minimal example I just created it works as expected... It has to do with something different and as soon as I find an example that describes my problem I will provide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem:
I was refreshing the content of my tree when selecting the pane where the tree is located on.
But instead of just updating it's nodes I recreated the complete model and that was the problem.
The path I was using was a path of the old model and this is the reason why the path couldn't be properly selected in the new tree. 
I switched to the approach of just updating the model and now setSelectionPath() has the effect I wanted it to have.

Answer (score 1):

To focus and expand the selected node:

1. `jtree.setScrollsOnExpand(true)`

   Determines whether the 
   tree might scroll to show previously hidden children.
   If this property is true (the default), 
   when a node expands the tree can use scrolling to make
   the maximum possible number of the node's descendants visible.
2. `jtree.setExpandsSelectedPaths(true)`
   Allows to configure the JTree to automatically expand selected paths.
   If you want to manage this manually,
   you can use `jtree.setExpandedState(TreePath path, boolean state)` method

Comment: Thanks but that that is not the effect I'm searching for... I will update my answer to make myself more clear

Comment: @Raven What does getSelectionRows() return after you apply setSelectionPath()?

Comment: @Raven then I think this is your problem. This is why you don't see selection. Compare with what the tree returns after user clicks a node.